# How to plot legend into multiple column outside the plot canvas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I [have a data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wgQQa-Toy113BR7gSUcH0ofy0dYBMBBu/view?usp=sharing) which consists of 131 columns and 4 rows. I am plotting it into python as follows

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.plot(figsize = (15,10))
```

Once it is plotted, all 131 legends are coming together like a huge tower over the line plots.

Please see the image here, which I have got :
[Link to Image, I have clipped after v82 for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njNhi.png)

I have found some solutions on Stackoverflow (SO) to shift legend anywhere in the plot but I could not find any solution to break this legend tower into multiple small-small pieces and stack them one beside another.

Moreover, I want my plot something look like this

My desired plot :

[image]

Any help would be appreciable. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the position of the legend in relative coordinates using `loc` and use `ncol` parameter to split the single legend column into multiple columns. To do so, you need an axis handle returned by the `df.plot`

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
ax = df.plot(figsize = (10,7))
ax.legend(loc=(1.01, 0.01), ncol=4)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]